# in Rails, How to manipulate a photo when try upload it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, crop

I am looking for a gem so that the user can crop it when choosing a photo.

The user clicks on "upload photo" and then when he selects his photo, a form appears for him to crop the photo. Since regardless of the size you upload, they must all have the same dimension

I have tried without success to use npm, cdn and libraries like Cropper, Croppi and Cropbox js

this is my code:

```
.form__group
  .upload__wrapper
    = f.input name, as: :file, input_html: { id: "image", :'data-label' => defined?(input_label) ? input_label : 'add file' }
    label = "Max 2
```

pdd: the photo upload does work, what I'm looking for is that once the user selects any photo, it automatically gives him the option to crop it

Comment: See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ith6FA0kxPc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permit the user to select a specific portion of the photo, than you should use something like Cropper JS or similar to allow that kind of UX/UI at the front-end level.
Once you know which portion the user selected, you have to send those data (for example x-y coordinates selected by user) to the back-end (rails controller, model ...).

At the back-end side you have to manipulate the photo, to crop it and this can be done for example with a gem such as kt-paperclip ( https://github.com/kreeti/kt-paperclip ).

That gem use imagemagick ( https://imagemagick.org/index.php ) commands which is really powerful and allow you to manipulate the photo in many different ways. You could write your own processor which apply imagemagick commands based on the input you provide to it.

Not sure, but maybe you could also achieve the same with ActiveStorage and image processing.
FYI https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html